# C++ getline() is only reading the last line in a text file

Tags: c++, file, getline

I am trying to read a text file and output every line but it only outputs the last line. How do I output every line? My code:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ReadFile("example.txt");
    std::string line;
    if (ReadFile.is_open())
    {
        while (std::getline(ReadFile, line));
        {
            std::cout << line << "\n";
        }
        ReadFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
}
```

I was following the example at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Txt file contents:

```
This is one line
This is another line
And a third line
```

Output:

https://i.imgur.com/t6XXmBG.png

There are other answers here that suggest adding endl or "\n" in the while loop but that is still not working for me.

Comment: Different platforms have different line ending conventions. (Windows vs old Mac vs Linux/Unix/macOS/Android/IOS) What platform are you on and where did the text file come from?

Comment: `while (std::getline(ReadFile, line));` <---- remove the semicolon

Comment: [Turn up your compiler's warning level](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/67qcs1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semicolon after the while loop which means it will keep iterating and do nothing as you have an empty statement (`;` means empty statement). This is why you got the last line as line was filled with the last line of your file in the last(3rd) iteration.

```
while (std::getline(ReadFile, line));
```

Update your while loop as shown below to get the desired result:

```
while (std::getline(ReadFile, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << "\n";
    }
```